# Can I upgrade the CPU in my Lenovo 3000 N100 laptop?

Tags: cpu, upgrade, lenovo-laptop

I've got an [Intel Core Duo T2300](http://ark.intel.com/products/27233/Intel-Core-Duo-Processor-T2300-(2M-Cache-1_66-GHz-667-MHz-FSB)) in my laptop ([Lenovo 3000 N100, 0768-49G](http://support.lenovo.com/en_US/product-and-parts/detail.page?&LegacyDocID=MIGR-63445)). Here is what I could find out about it:

```
$ sudo dmidecode 
# dmidecode 2.11
SMBIOS 2.4 present.
42 structures occupying 1436 bytes.
Table at 0x000DC010.

Handle 0x0000, DMI type 0, 24 bytes
BIOS Information
        Vendor: LENOVO
        Version: 61ET37WW
        Release Date: 06/04/07
        Address: 0xE6B70

[...]
Handle 0x0002, DMI type 2, 8 bytes
Base Board Information
        Manufacturer: LENOVO
        Product Name: CAPELL VALLEY(NAPA) CRB
[...]

Handle 0x0004, DMI type 4, 35 bytes
Processor Information
    Socket Designation: U2E1
    Type: Central Processor
    Family: Other
    Manufacturer: Intel
    ID: E8 06 00 00 FF FB E9 BF
    Version: Genuine Intel(R) CPU           T2300  @ 1.66GHz
    Voltage: 3.3 V
    External Clock: 166 MHz
    Max Speed: 2048 MHz
    Current Speed: 1600 MHz
    Status: Populated, Enabled
    Upgrade: ZIF Socket
    L1 Cache Handle: 0x0005
    L2 Cache Handle: 0x0006
    L3 Cache Handle: Not Provided
    Serial Number: Not Specified
    Asset Tag: Not Specified
    Part Number: Not Specified

$ cat /proc/cpuinfo 
processor   : 0
vendor_id   : GenuineIntel
cpu family  : 6
model       : 14
model name  : Genuine Intel(R) CPU           T2300  @ 1.66GHz
stepping    : 8
microcode   : 0x39
cpu MHz     : 1000.000
cache size  : 2048 KB
```

I believe the chipset is "Mobile Intel 945GM Express", but I don't know how to verify it on a Linux system.

I'm not sure about the socket, but Intel claims "Sockets Supported: PBGA479, PPGA478".
Now, I'd like to upgrade to the **fastest compatible CPU available**, but I'm a bit lost in all the details. Can you guys help me out with a couple of questions, please?

1. What CPUs can I choose from? (I think it's only the Core2Duo line, but it should be enough for an upgrade)
2. Can I use a 64-bit CPU?
3. Can I use a CPU with a higher FSB than 667 MHz?
4. Do I have to worry about additional cooling, or is it enough to check for similar voltage/TDP values?

Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you look at the Lenovo link you provided, they give you a list of compatible processors:

> Intel Celeron M processor:
>
> - 420(1.6GHz), 1MB L2 cache
> - 430(1.73GHz), 1MB L2 cache
>
> Intel Core Solo processor:
>
> - T1300(1.66GHz), 2MB L2 cache
>
> Intel Pentium dual-core processor:
>
> - T2060(1.6GHz), 1MB L2 cache
>
> Intel Core Duo processor:
>
> - T2250(1.73GHz), 2MB L2 cache
> - T2350(1.86GHz), 2MB L2 cache
> - T2300(1.66GHz), 2MB L2 cache
> - T2300E(1.66GHz), 2MB L2 cache
> - T2400(1.83GHz), 2MB L2 cache
> - T2500(2GHz), 2MB L2 cache
>
> Intel Core 2 Duo processor:
>
> - T5200(1.6GHz), 2MB L2 cache
> - T5500(1.66GHz), 2MB L2 cache
> - T5600(1.83GHz), 2MB L2 cache
> - **T7200(2GHz), 4MB L2 cache**

I've highlighted the fastest one they say will work.

Comment: Thank you, techie007! This implies the answers to my other questions are: (2) 64 bit is fine, (3) FSB should be the same. Since 7200/7400/7600 seem to be all compatible - do you think it's worth going for the fastest CPU clock? This would touch my fourth question.

Comment: It should be fine with the stock cooling.

Comment: I just upgraded from a T2300E to T7200. Here's the story: http://blog.nu42.com/2012/09/the-cpu-in-my-laptop-and-headlights-on.html

Comment: "Long story short" - thanks for the SuperUser shout-out. ;)